# Vue.delete warning to avoid using JavaScript unary operator as property name on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get the following warning when using Vue.delete:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template: avoid using JavaScript unary operator as property name: "delete(testObj,)" in expression @click="Vue.delete(testObj,'label')"
```

I can use Vue.delete anywhere else and it seems fine. Am I using it wrong?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testObj: {
        label: "The label"
      }
    };
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{testObj.label}}
  <button @click="Vue.delete(testObj,'label')">Delete</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global `Vue` will not be available inside your template. Everything in a template is scoped to the current Vue *instance*, so you're effectively trying to access `this.Vue`. Trying to access any of the properties of the global `Vue` won't work.

You can use `$delete` instead of `Vue.delete` inside a template.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-delete

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testObj: {
        label: "The label"
      }
    };
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{testObj.label}}
  <button @click="$delete(testObj, 'label')">Delete</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I would add that the specific error message you're seeing relates more generally to trying to use any property called `delete` but that's something of a moot point as you should be using `$delete` anyway.